# windows application in vb.net for calculating student marks

Tags: vb.net

I need to make a vb.net windows application for calculating the student marks.I have three valuations.For example if valution1 is 45 marks and if valuation2 has 30 then there is 15 marks difference so valuation3 has to be done.Then average will be calculated by adding valuation 3 with maximum score of valuation1 and valuation2.valuation3 is done only when there is a difference of 15 or more marks in valuation1 and valuation2.Please help me to make this application as i am new to coding.

Comment: You're on the wrong site, try [gimmetehcodez.com](http://gimmetehcodez.com/).

Comment: @TheBlueDog, haha! Looks like you really did too much of research for getting a domain name that is not actually taken :p

Comment: @Error404: Aye, it's tough at the top. ;)

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it (by clicking on the green tick-mark next to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Get three textboxes, set the third textbox's enabled property to false. The following code will help you (under textbox's textchanged event).

```
Private Sub Hello () Handles Textbox1.Textchanged, Textbox2.Textchanged
     If Val(Textbox1.Text) - Val(Textbox2.Text) >= 15 then
           Textbox3.Enabled = True
     Else
           Textbox3.Enabled = False
     End If
End Sub
```

For average, you need to add all the values and then divide by number of terms. Suppose you display the average in a label:

```
Dim a as integer
If Textbox3.Enabled = True then
  a = Val(Textbox1.Text) + Val(Textbox2.Text) + Val(Textbox3.Text)
  Label1.Text = a/3
Else
  a = Val(Textbox1.Text) + Val(Textbox2.Text)
  Label1.Text = a/2
End If
```

I hope you understand! This was a type of homework, but I did it just because I was bored. Please don't ask such questions in the future. Read the 'How to Ask' guide next time.